# Changing div background color when a link inside the div is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this button that is just actually a div and I have a link inside the div

```
<div id='button'>
    <a href='#'>Link</a>
</div>
```

I am able to use CSS to change the background color when the link is hovered over. However, how do I make the background color change when the link is clicked? I believe this requires some javascript?
If so, can you guys help me with the java script? This is what I came up so far and yet it still does not work.

```
  <a href="/page/login" onmousedown="document.getElementById('button').backgroundColor='lavender'">login</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would controll it with JavaScript and CSS. The following example will toggle the background color of the button with each click. This is done by adding the class `clicked`to the `div`, or remove it, if the div has already got this class.

the html code with inline javascript:

```
<div id="button">
    <a href="#" onmousedown="javascript:(btn=document.getElementById('button')).className = (btn.className  == 'clicked') ? '' : 'clicked';">Link</a>
</div>
```

the css:

```
#button {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#button.clicked {
    background-Color: #123abc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using :

```
<div id='button'>
    <a href='#' onmousedown="this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='lavender';">Link</a>
</div>
```

Note that you can use the same code without modifying on any Anchor or other elements as it will be applied to whatever parent object is.

Answer (score 1):

```
onmousedown="document.getElementById('button').style.backgroundColor='lavender'"
```